# Setting android:layout_margin for a view through code

Tags: android, android-view

In my application i am creating a LinearLayout. When i am adding other views to the Layout they appears too close (Difference between two views is very narrow). I want to set `android:layout_margin` for the views adding inside the Layout. How it is poosible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

params.setMargins(10, 20, 30, 40);

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("some text");
layout.addView(button, params);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to do it via xml then just do this

```
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"   //example
android:layout_marginRight="10dp" 
android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
```

wherever you want to have a margin either left, right, top or bottom

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  my_params;             
 my_params= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(12,12);    
 my_params.leftMargin =57;    
 my_params.topMargin =143;     
 rl_main.addView(mProgress,my_params);
```

Here **rl_main** is main layout
      And **mprogress** is the added object.